Error: `browserContext.addCookies: Cookie should have either url or domain` in Playwright with MongoDB Cookies
I'm working on an authentication flow using Playwright to authenticate a user based on cookies stored in MongoDB. I'm fetching these cookies and trying to add them to the browser context using context.addCookies(). However, I'm encountering the following error:
Error during authentication: browserContext.addCookies: Cookie should have either url or domain

Code:
Here is the relevant part of my code:
export const authenticateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  let browser: Browser | null = null;

  try {
    const { userId } = req.body;

    // Fetch cookies from MongoDB
    const reviewAuth = await ReviewAuth.findOne({ userId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) });

    if (!reviewAuth || !reviewAuth.attributeCookies) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "No cookies found for this user." });
    }

    // Process cookies
    let cookiesData = reviewAuth.attributeCookies.map((cookie: any) => {
      console.log("Processing cookie: ", cookie);

      // Handle __Host- cookies
      if (cookie.name.startsWith("__Host-")) {
        cookie.secure = true;
        cookie.path = "/";
        delete cookie.domain;  // __Host- cookies cannot have a domain
        if (!cookie.url) {
          cookie.url = "https://myaccount.google.com";  // Set a default URL for __Host- cookies
        }
      } else {
        // If the domain exists, remove the URL
        if (cookie.domain) {
          delete cookie.url;
        } else if (cookie.url) {
          // If only the URL exists, extract the domain
          const urlObject = new URL(cookie.url);
          cookie.domain = urlObject.hostname;
        }

        // Filter out cookies that have neither domain nor URL
        if (!cookie.domain && !cookie.url) {
          console.warn(`Invalid cookie: missing both domain and url`);
          return null;
        }
      }

      return cookie;
    }).filter((cookie: any) => cookie !== null);  // Filter invalid cookies

    if (cookiesData.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No valid cookies found to authenticate." });
    }

    // Launch browser and set cookies
    browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    await context.addCookies(cookiesData);

    // Navigate to Google Maps
    await context.newPage().goto("https://www.google.com/maps", { waitUntil: "networkidle" });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Authenticated successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error during authentication:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      setTimeout(() => browser.close(), 60000);
    }
  }
};

The Cookie Schema:
Here is the MongoDB schema for the cookies:
const reviewAuthSchema = new Schema<IReviewAuth>({
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: false },
  placeID: { type: String, required: false },
  attributeCookies: [
    new Schema({
      domain: { type: String, required: false },
      name: { type: String, required: false },
      path: { type: String, required: false },
      sameSite: { type: String, required: false },
      secure: { type: Boolean, required: false },
      httpOnly: { type: Boolean, required: false },
      value: { type: String, required: false },
      url: { type: String, required: false }
    }, { _id: false })
  ]
});

Sample Data:
Here's an example of the data stored in MongoDB for attributeCookies:
{
  "domain": ".google.com",
  "httpOnly": false,
  "name": "__Host-3PLSID",
  "path": "/",
  "sameSite": "None",
  "secure": false,
  "value": "o.myaccount.google.com|...",
  "url": "https://myaccount.google.com"
},
{
  "domain": ".google.com",
  "httpOnly": false,
  "name": "__Secure-3PSID",
  "path": "/",
  "sameSite": "None",
  "secure": false,
  "value": "g.a000pAgxXnjppz5NK5oq..."
}

Issue:
Despite ensuring that each cookie has either a valid url or domain, I still encounter the error mentioned above. I’ve handled __Host- cookies by setting a valid url and removing domain, but Playwright continues to raise this error when adding cookies via context.addCookies().
I've tried:

Ensuring url is set for __Host- cookies.
Removing url when domain is present.
Filtering out cookies missing both url and domain.

Question:
What could be causing this error in Playwright? How can I ensure that each cookie is correctly formatted to be accepted by context.addCookies()?
Any help would be appreciated!
